# How to get object position and size in UIView objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, cgrect

I put UIImageView in my Scene from Object library, and give it an image and defined OUTLET in .h file. Now I want to check its coordinates, or center point, or frame X,Y,Width,Height.
I am using 
This

```
CGRect newFrameSize = CGRectMake(recycleBin.frame.origin.x, recycleBin.frame.origin.y,
recycleBin.frame.size.width, recycleBin.frame.size.height);
```

or

```
CGRect newFrameSize = recycleBin.frame;
```

by using this

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrameSize));
```

gives same result that is

> 2013-01-16 21:42:25.101 xyzapp[6474:c07] {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

I want its actual position and size when viewcontroller loaded, so when user click on image view it will fadeout by zoom-in towards users and will disappear, and when user tap on reset button, it fadein and zoom-in back to original form (reverse to the previous animation).
Also give me hint, how to perform this animation on UIImageView or any button or label. Thx

Comment: When is this code being called? Is it in `-viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yes above code is called in -viewDidLoad for saving image view frame to newFrameSize for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't check an item's actual frame as set in IB in `-viewDidLoad`. The earliest you can check it (that I've found) is by overriding `-viewDidAppear:`. But, since `-viewDidAppear:` could be called multiple times throughout the life of the view, you need to make sure you're not saving the frame it's in the modified state.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if(savedFrame == CGRectZero) {
        savedFrame = self.recycleBin.frame;
        NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(savedFrame));
    }
}
```

Where `savedFrame` is a member variable (or you could make it a property).

From the description of the animation you're wanting, it sounds like adjusting the frame isn't the way to go about it. It sounds like you're wanting to get the effect of the view stretching and fading out (and the reverse when being reset)? If so, some code like this might be more so what you're looking for...

Fade out:

```
float animationDuration = 2.0f; // Duration of animation in seconds
float zoomScale = 3.0f; // How much to zoom in duration the animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomScale, zoomScale);
    self.recycleBin.transform = transform;
    self.recycleBin.alpha = 0; // Make fully transparent
}];
```

And then, to reset the view:

```
float animationDuration = 2.0f; // Duration of animation in seconds
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
    self.recycleBin.transform = transform;
    self.recycleBin.alpha = 1.0; // Make fully opaque
}];
```

You can play around with the numbers to see if you get the effects you desire. Most animations in iOS are actually extremely simple to do. This code would work for any UIView subclass.

Comment: yes solved my problem. 1 thing, what is CGRectZero... I am doing this for saving original state.. is this correct?

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    recycleBinFrameoriginal = recycleBin.frame;
    
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(recycleBinFrameoriginal));
}

Comment: I have the `if` in there in case the user navigates away from that view controller while it's in the non-default state and then comes back to it. That'll result in `-viewDidAppear:` being called a second time, saving the wrong value (if the check isn't performed). Checking to make sure `recycleBinFrameoriginal` is equal to CGRectZero ensures that it's only updated the first time that instance of the view appears.

Comment: This definately saved my future....  Sir when I put if (recycleBinFrameoriginal == CGRectZero) {
        <#statements#>
    }
it gives an error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') and 'CGRect')

Comment: found just use if (CGRectEqualToRect (
                           recycleBinFrameoriginal,
                           CGRectZero
                           )) { //commands } worked for comparing... thanks

Comment: Also your animation code works good, but the only problem comes when the animation began it shows in different coordinates then original coordinates. I use same but with different style. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your IBOutlet is not attached to your class.

Open up your view controller header file (if that is where you property declaration is) and look beside the declaration:

[image]

Notice how on the first IBOutlet, the circle (to the left of the line number) is filled in.  This means that it is connected to your scene.  However, the second one is not (the circle is not filled in).

Comment: It looks like it should work then.  Try `NSLog(@"%@", recycleBin);`.  I'm guessing that is is `nil`?

Comment: no work.. but get results by puting it in - viewDidAppear .. Thanks